# A question that might genuinely satisfy "occurs in a philosophical context but is not itself philosophical"

Tags: discussion

I've had my doubts about that VTC parameter, but unfortunately I seem as if I might've proven by doubts wrong.

So, while trying to zip together some themes in my notes on set theory, I got to where I decided to email Paul Corazza and Lawrence Moss. Corazza is probably more recognizable among set theorists while Moss contributed the SEP article on non-wellfounded set theory. The issue is something to do with a way to generate ill-founded sets in the "middle" of the cumulative hierarchy using a peculiar embedding axiom scheme. Corazza confirmed that the scheme would end up ill-founded, but Moss was no longer as familiar with embedding theory as he felt would be helpful in evaluating my question.

To present my question here, then, I'd have to try to quickly synopsize a lot of the more cryptic set-theoretic lore out there, because I'd be framing the argument with a lot of technical representations of critical points and antitone sequences and whatever. The conclusion, if it followed in a valid enough way from the premises by way of the (not entirely stable) inference rules, would be relevant to the philosophy of mathematics in the sense that it would be an illustration of how to "force" a foundationalist theory of mathematics into a non-foundationalist state, or rather to expand the context to include well-founded and ill-founded terms. As a philosophical question, the issue might be written down as, "Is it possible for sets to have some elements in a well-founded way, but also to have other elements in an ill-founded way, rather than sets only having elements in one such way?"

But again, my attempt to solve this problem goes through a dense labyrinth of concepts. So it seems like it would be answerable by MathOF folks. However, for one example of why I am wary of asking them about this, I semi-recently offered an answer to some other contributor's question over there, and I wrote the technical lines down with an existential quantifier typed before a universal quantifier. So the multiply upvoted and sole comment offered by a more senior MathOF contributor was something about how universal quantifiers are supposed to be typed before existential ones, which discouraged me to consider.

I was even more discouraged when I went back to the SEP article on Quine/NF/U-style set theories which I had based some of my response on, and I saw that they had typed an existential quantifier on the same line as a universal one, and yet before typing that universal one. So now I don't know why I was corrected over on the MathOF; for a moment, I thought I had transgressed against some factoid of the Lévy hierarchy (some "prenex normal form" rule), but now I'm not sure.

I could also try the mathematics subreddit (the set theory subreddit seems half-dead, though), but I'm even warier of that option. Or so I could just keep emailing random professors. I do suspect Hamkins probably knows the answers, or would know them, "on sight" but he's an active enough researcher (more than enough!) so I don't know that trying to waylay him online with what might turn out to be a weak question, would be worth his (or my) time.

Comment: Are you inquiring whether your intended question is on topic for Philosophy SE? It is hard to make sense of your post, which is needlessly long.Many of your impressions are irrelevant for the issue of a post being on topic vs. off-topic; some are not even intelligible (as in "*I might've proven by doubts wrong*"); others seem truncated ("*which discouraged me to consider.*" ... consider what?). Also your assumption that the audience is acquainted with the multitude of references might not be realistic and may be perceived as pedantic ("transgressed against some factoid of the Lévy hierarchy").

Comment: @IñakiViggers I have had a publicly stated issue with the VTC parameter "occurs in a philosophical context but is not philosophical." This meta-question seems to involve proof that there can be first-order questions that satisfy such a parameter, contrary to my prior judgment. I was discouraged by reflecting on the fact, on the MathOF, that a citation of an academic source, in an accepted academic format, was met with as much quibbling as it was met with. Anyway, I expect respondents to this meta-question to be familiar with my post history on the PhilosophySE.